# Git: reset to a too old commit, and git log , only show from the commit I have now

Tags: git

Today I use `git`, commit , the info is: `2016-11-25`.

and after I do something wrong, I reset back to a old `commit` which info is:`2016-10-18` careless.

and now I want to go to the `2016-11-25`, but when I `git log`, not show my `commit`:

[image: now only show from the commit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Git's reflog feature, which is a sort of audit trail of all the things which happen as you use Git, including commits.

```
git reflog --date=iso
```

Try to find an entry looking something like the following:

```
b28ae3b HEAD@{2016-11-25 15:54:53 +0800}: commit: message for the commit which you
made earlier today
```

If you can find the commit, record the SHA-1 hash (`b23ae3b` in this example) because you will need it to restore your branch at that commit.  Now restore your branch via the following:

```
git checkout yourBranch
git reset --hard b28ae3b
```

Comment: i will try and reply